# Reading Through A List of Files, then Sending those Files via FTP

Tags: bash, ftp, ftp-client, grads

I am making weather model charts with the Grads scripting language, and I am using a bash script so I can use a while loop to download model data (in grib2 format) and call the grads scripts for each frame on the model run. Right now, I have a loop that runs through all the scripts for a given forecast hour and uploads the image output via FTP. After this for loop completes, the grib2 data for the next hour is downloaded, and the loop runs again.

```
for ((i=0;i<${#SCRIPTS[@]};i++)); do
    #define filename
    FILENAME="${FILENAMES[i]}${FORECASTHOUR}hrfcst.png" 
    #run grads script
    /home/mint/opengrads/Contents/opengrads -lbc "run /home/mint/opengrads/Contents/plotscripts/${SCRIPTS[i]} $CTLFILE $INIT_STRINGDATE $INIT_INTDATE $INITHOUR $FILENAME $h $MODEL $MODELFORTITLE 500"
    #run ftp script
    #sh /home/mint/opengrads/Contents/bashscripts/ftpsample.sh $INIT_INTDATE $INITHOUR $FILENAME $MODEL
done
```

This is inelegant because I open and close an FTP session each time I send a single image. I would much rather write the names of the filenames for a given forecast hour to a .txt file (ex: have a "echo ${FILENAME} >> FILEOFFILENAMES.txt" in the loop) and have my FTP script read and send all those files in a single session. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. You can add this to your shell script to generate the ftp script and then have it run after you've generated the files:

```
echo open $HOST > ftp.txt
echo user $USER $PASS >> ftp.txt
find . -type f -name '*hrfcst.png' -printf "put destination/%f %f\n" >> ftp.txt
echo bye >> ftp.txt

ftp < ftp.txt
```

The above code will generate file ftp.txt with commands and pass that to ftp. The generated ftp.txt will look like:

```
open host
user user pass
put destination/forecast1.hrfcst.png forecast1.hrfcst.png
put destination/forecast2.hrfcst.png forecast2.hrfcst.png
put destination/forecast3.hrfcst.png forecast3.hrfcst.png
...
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will upload all files added today from local directory to remote ftp directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'

# Local directory where the files are stored.
cd "/local/directory/from where to upload files/"

# To get all the files added today only.
TODAYSFILES=`find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1`


# remote server directory to upload backup
REMOTEDIR="/directory on remote ftp computer/"

for FILENAME in ${TODAYSFILES[@]}; do
  ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
  ascii
  user $USER $PASSWD
  prompt
  cd $REMOTEDIR
  put $FILENAME
  bye
  EOT
done
```